# Is reloid from PG_CLASS_INFO table unique if table is dropped and recreated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

As in title says `reloid` from [PG_CLASS_INFO](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_CLASS_INFO.html) table unique if table is dropped and recreated. This should not be any different from `postgresql`

Comment: Isn't it easier to try it out than ask in SO?

Comment: I did not have access to redshift at that time :) answer to this is yes its different

Answer (score 0):

Did some test now that I have access to redshift. Answer is yes, it will be unique every time a table with same name is created.

1. Created first time

```
reloid:4575765
schemaname:test-subs
tablename:testtable
relcreationtime:2021-10-03 00:10:38.595259
```

2. `drop table if exists "test-subs"."testtable"`
3. Create same table again

```
reloid:4575843
schemaname:test-subs
tablename:testtable
relcreationtime:2021-10-03 00:16:43.059861
```